# How can I pass ds variable to a function within a dag?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I want to pass the execution date, which is in the variable {{ ds }}. However, I passed it through a function it does not get the execution date.

```
def get_spark_step_2(date):
      #logic in here
      return step

exec_date = '{{ ds }}'

step_adder2 = EmrAddStepsOperator(
    task_id='create_parquets',
    job_flow_id="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull('create_job_flow', key='return_value') }}",
    aws_conn_id='aws_default',
    steps=get_spark_step_2(exec_date),
    dag=dag
)
```

Do you know how I can use the variable in the context above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class that extends EmrAddStepsOperator, and make `steps` a templated field.

Something like this:

```py
class MyEmrAddStepsOperator(EmrAddStepsOperator):

    template_fields = ['job_flow_id','steps']
```

`EmrAddStepsOperator` itself only has `job_flow_id` as a templated field:

```py
class EmrAddStepsOperator(BaseOperator):
    """
    An operator that adds steps to an existing EMR job_flow.
    :param job_flow_id: id of the JobFlow to add steps to
    :type job_flow_name: str
    :param aws_conn_id: aws connection to uses
    :type aws_conn_id: str
    :param steps: boto3 style steps to be added to the jobflow
    :type steps: list
    """
    template_fields = ['job_flow_id']
```

You can only use macros (like `ds`) in fields that are templated.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for this silly question, only with that small variation, Do I need to define _init_ and execute in that extended class?

Comment: Shouldn't need to add anything